# Discriminant Analysis Graph

Tags: sas

I run a discriminant analysis & want to visualize the result. That means I want to check how well the discriminant functions demarcate dthe groups visually. Can anybody tell me how to do it. the discriminant code is given below:

```
proc discrim data=test out=ldaout;
class Classification;
var cvar1 var2 var3 var4;
run;
```

Comment: I think this is not a good site for that. I suggest Statistical Analysis http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since this is more of a coding problem than a statistical problem, that's why I posted the question here. I just want to know the code of sas of how to generate the graph. I can interpret the result.

Comment: In that case, you would want to describe more about the graph you want to create. I am a statistical developer but not sure what you specifically want to draw.

Comment: In R, we use plot(lda) to plot the 2 groups & visually check whether the groups are distinct or not. I want to plot the same graph using SAS. There are some examples in Base SAS stat discrim procedure.But they have used macro. I just want to plot it simply.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant scatterplot matrix by plot(lda) in R.

If you have 9.2, you would have proc SGScatter, refer to following for more details

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/057-2010.pdf

Comment: Thank you! But I've sas 9.1, Can't I do it in 9.1?

Comment: In my experience with SAS, I don't think you can do that in 9.1, but you can call SAS about it for sure.

Comment: You can probably use the GPLOT procedure to get what your after, but you mignt need to build an annotate dataset if you're trying to customize the chart.

Comment: Thanks RWill! I didn't notice your comment earlier.

Comment: Thanks Shin for your answer. But unfortunately  SGScatter is not working in SAS 9.1.3

Comment: That's too bad. At this point, Proc Graph and gplot seem to be the only solution. But without macro, it may be cumbersome. BTW, do you have to use SAS for graph? If not, you can extract SAS data, for example, to plot in R.

Comment: No. Actually I got into a strange problem, so wanted to test the results in SAS graph. When I'm running Discriminant Analysis in SAS, the variables shows it perfectly discriminating the groups. But when I was running the DA with the same vars in R & plotting it I find the groups are overlapping. So, Just want to check in the SAS graph itself how the DA plots look like.